# In JavaScript, or jQuery, how do I accurately grab an attribute to manipulate the active selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ultimately I'm wanting the user to click on the Landing Page next to an image on either Print or Mug. Then on the Order Page have the button for Print/Mug be active and then the image that's associated be marked as well.

So I have in Landing Page the following code:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/someurl?image=main_image.jpg&type=print active">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/someurl?image=main_image.jpg&type=mug active">Mug</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then in the Order Page the following code:

```
        <div class="img-container1 image-container" image_var="main_image.jpg">
      <%= image_tag('main_image.jpg') %>
      <div class="wk-after">
        <div class="centered-wk">
          <span class="fa fa-check-circle check-circle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="centered-wk wk-select">
          SELECTED
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My thought process was to then grab from the Order Page the image_var attribute and make it active.

So far I've been using:

```
    <script>
  function toggleActive() {
    var activeElements = document.querySelectorAll('image_var');
    activeElements.forEach(function (el) {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    });

    btn.classList.add('active');
  }
</script>
```

This isn't working. I don't know what the best way to grab the image_var or a url parameter. What am I missing?

I've also tried:

```
<script>
      function toggleActive() {
        var activeElements = document.querySelectorAll('[image-var]');
        activeElements.forEach(function (el) {
          el.classList.remove('active');
        });

        btn.classList.add('active');
      }
    </script>
```

With an update to the div on the container to be image-var to match. Still not touching the image.

I feel like this should be working with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $.url.attr('image')
      $.url.attr('type')
    });
    </script>
```

Wouldn't this be pulling out the main_image.jpg and then the print from type?

Comment: Define "This isn't working". What exactly is it doing?

Comment: It's not actually grabbing the image_var and making it active. Honestly I don't know the best way to grab the attribute. I do know that classList is probably the best method to be applying the active selector to it. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you should look at the docs for `querySelectorAll` and then learn about CSS selectors. You are using it wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: I'm trying to find the attribute associated with the div tag then change it to be active on page load. Maybe querySelectorAll is the wrong use. I know I need to find the url parameter.